# conditionally import a .py or a .pyd module?

Tags: python

I have two modules, a "module.py" and a "module.pyd" that implements the same functions. Both modules are in the same folder. I'd would like to create a unit test that tests both the python and the extension modules against some data.

Is there any way in which I could conditionally import the .py module or the .pyd?

I could do some renaming before importing, but I would prefer a solution like being able to do import “module.py” or import “module.pyd”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the native version to `_module`, and have the pure-Python version conditionally run

```
from _module import *
```

after the rest of its code unless a specific debugging flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
if blah:
    import x
else:
    import y
```

Comment: But `x` and `y` are both `module`. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This solution suggests renaming them beyond just the extension.

Comment: This solution says nothing about renaming them; it just uses two names with no explanation. Also, you'd want to use `import as` to adjust the names, or your test code will be awkward.